# Eclipse GDB stacktrace gets file location wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, gdb, android-ndk

It seems Eclipse is easily confused when doing debugging using GDB. In the project there is a DownloadManager.cpp file which contains JNI glue code to run code within the Shared Libraries DownloadManager.cpp.

Eclipse seems to be easily confused and does not relate the stack trace to the correct file. The problem occurred in **SVI::DownloadManager::activeDownloads()** which is not in the JNI glue code's DownloadManager.cpp, but in the Shared Libraries.

Clicking on the stack trace frame results in Eclipse opening the wrong file and highlighting the wrong line. Any advice or help on this is appreciated.

Kevin

*Eclipse loads the wrong file upon double clicking leading to confusion*
[image: Eclipse wrong file]

*The actual line number that was shown in the stack trace*
[image: Eclipse right file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename one of the `DownloadManager.cpp` files to something else and file a bug against `CDT`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up doing!